# Confused how to customize meteor verification email

Tags: meteor

How do I get the verification link from the default Meteor method into a custom email method I have that uses sendgrid stmp.

here is the meteor verification method that works well on its own and has the link I want:

```
sendVerificationLink() {
 let userId = Meteor.userId();
   if ( userId ) {
     return Accounts.sendVerificationEmail( userId );
    }
  },
```

Here is my custom method that uses sendgrid, everything works except for I cant figure out how to get the link with the custom token:

```
'signupEmail' (submission) {
   this.unblock();
   const link = ''
   const message = `welcome ${submission.firstname} `
   const text = `welcome ${submission.firstname}. Please verify your 
   account ${link}`
   Email.send({
     from: "hi@test.com",
     to: submission.email,
     subject: message,
     text: text,
      html: text,
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone is looking for this in the future I found an answer on Meteor forums:  https://forums.meteor.com/t/how-to-get-verification-link-for-custom-sent-verification-email/22932/2

Basically I added a token record and saved it in the database. Then used the token with the method: Accounts.urls.verifyEmail which created the link to insert in the email.

Here is my final method:

```
'signupEmail' (submission) {
    this.unblock();
    let userId = Meteor.userId();
    var tokenRecord = {
      token: Random.secret(),
      address: submission.email,
      when: new Date()};

      Meteor.users.update(
        {_id: userId},
        {$push: {'services.email.verificationTokens': tokenRecord}}
      );
      const verifyEmailUrl = Accounts.urls.verifyEmail(tokenRecord.token);

      const message = `welcome ${submission.firstname} `
      const text = `welcome ${submission.firstname}. Please verify your account ${verifyEmailUrl}`
      Email.send({
        from: "hi@test.com",
        to: submission.email,
        subject: message,
        text: text,
        html: text,
      });
  },
```

Comment: I'm not sure you need to create a new token - one should be created in the user record for you automatically when you create a new user.